# How can I change locale of calendar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to change calendar language from English to Korean. But it showed some error on it.

This is the error:

> No MaterialLocalizations found. DatePickerDialog widgets require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor. The material library uses Localizations to generate messages, labels, and abbreviations.

And this is my code. I already changed `pubspec.yaml`

```
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart'; // library

Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
return  MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  home: buildHomePage(),
);

Future<void> _selectrequestDate(BuildContext context) async {
final DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    locale : Locale('kr',''),
    initialDate: requestDate,
    firstDate: DateTime(2015),
    lastDate: DateTime(2050));
if (pickedDate != null && pickedDate != requestDate)
  setState(() {
    requestDate = pickedDate;
  });
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hey @Malone facing the same issue now. Added the supported locale part, but still happens. It seems like you accepted the answer. Curious how you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Internationalizing Flutter apps](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#setting-up), you also need to add `supportedLocales` in your `MaterialApp`:

```dart
return const MaterialApp(
  title: 'Localizations Sample App',
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
    Locale('es', ''), // Spanish, no country code
  ],
  home: MyHomePage(),
);
```

Comment: I tried it, but same error occurred too

Comment: Have you done a hot restart in your app to make sure the changes have effect? (not to confuse with hot reload)

Comment: Sure. I stopped and restart it. But I don't think it is changed.